# Using ReportTransactStatus in XCM give me a unroutable error

Tags: xcm, xcmv3

I am getting an **'Unroutable'** error when setting an `Error Handler` using `ReportTransactStatus` in my XCM Message.

I  am using the `polkadot-v1.0.0`, at V3 of XCM.

```rust
match send_xcm::<T::XcmSender>(
    (Parent, Junction::Parachain(mult_para_id.into())).into(),
    Xcm(vec![
        SetErrorHandler(Xcm(vec![ReportTransactStatus(QueryResponseInfo {
            destination: Parachain(2000).into(),
            query_id,
            max_weight: Weight::from_all(0),
        })])),
        Transact {
            origin_kind: OriginKind::Native,
            require_weight_at_most: Weight::from_parts(1_000, 1_000),
            call: <T as Config>::RuntimeCall::from(Call::<T>::xcm_clone_file {
                signer,
                energy_bank_file: new_file
            })
            .encode()
            .into(),
        },
        ExpectTransactStatus(MaybeErrorCode::Success),
    ]),
) {
    Ok((hash, cost)) => Self::deposit_event(Event::Success(mult_para_id)),
    Err(e) => Self::deposit_event(Event::Error(e, mult_para_id)),
}
```

When no error occurs in the destiny, everything executes without problems. However, when an error happens the destiny parachain outputs the `unroutable` error.

That is confusing me because the channel is open in both ways, `2000 > 2001` and `2001 > 2000`.

Is that the correct way of checking if the XCM call was executed without errors in the destiny?
What I am doing wrong here and how could I fix it?

I would really appreciate any kind of help or directions in how to properly do this.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the destination in `SetErrorHandler` to `{parents:1, Parachain(2000)}`, It would be executed on Parachain(2001) when error occurs, and the location of Parachain(2000) **relative to** Parachain(2001) is `parents: 1, Parachain(2000)`